# HTTPS: 400 Bad request! Invalid JSON

Tags: json, ruby, rest, api, rest-client

I am trying to pass a POST method request for a specific URI using the `Restclient` gem. I am however, continously getting `400 Bad request` from the server. I have tried numerous ways of posting the data, with modifications. PFB the current one

```
require 'minitest'
require 'rest-client'
require 'json'
require 'pry'
require 'uri/https'


#class APITest < Minitest::Test
def setup
  response = RestClient.post("", {'userType' => 'nonsso', 'firstName' => 'Justin9', 'isDependentMajor' => true, 'email' => 'randomemail0053@gmail.com', 'dependentName'=> 'Cobb', 'dependentLastName' => 'Cobb', 'lastName' => 'Justin'
  }, { "Content-Type" => 'application/json'})
  puts response
end



setup
```

I am at a loss to understand what am I missing here. I tried using the same code, for an other api, with get method, only with `headers` and it works.

Please can someone let me know, any bad syntax in json I am using for the `POST` method.

Answer (score 3):

```
 response = RestClient.post("", {'userType' => 'nonsso', 'firstName' => 'Justin9', 'isDependentMajor' => true, 'email' => 'randomemail0053@gmail.com', 'dependentName'=> 'Cobb', 'dependentLastName' => 'Cobb', 'lastName' => 'Justin'
  }.to_json, { "Content-Type" => 'application/json'})
```

Note the `to_json`.

`RestClient` serializes the payload in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` by default. You have to manually serialize your post data.

Comment: I tried adding `to_json` earlier, but it didn't work. Still bad request and invalid JSON :(

Comment: With you current code also, I receive the same thing. I tried re-checking with the post man tool and the same url with parameters works there

Comment: Works! I guess, I was leaving spaces between the data's here. I tried removing those spaces and now it appears to be working. :)

Comment: I feel like a dumb now, that I was wasting one whole friday, just because, I didnt give spaces between the data. Damn it!

Comment: `{'userType'=>'nonsso','firstName'=>'Justin9','isDependentMajor'=>true, 'email' => 'randomemail00533@gmail.com','dependentName'=>'Cobb','dependentLastName'=>'Cobb','lastName'=>'Justin'}.to_json, { "Content-Type" => 'application/json'})
  puts response`

Comment: Weird. Spaces should not be an issue.

Comment: True! I wanted one more help, is there a way to retry `post` in case the first time it fails? 

like could i give an `if` `else?`. `until response.body.include? "200" retry?`

I basically, want this code, to try three times to post, and if still fails, `puts`  the api has failed.